# Solution Explorer - custom icons for my folders

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is there any way I can change the icon for my folders? In a large MVC project with a number of areas, it would be nice to see that Controllers, Model and Views have a different icon (or text).

Folder with M or V or C would be nice. I can create those if I know how to substitue them in. Even on a project by project based change.

Here is a screenie showing that some system type folders have different icons.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to the following post, it is possible, but you will need to create your own project subtype:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsx/thread/7403bcaf-6389-4a9f-b64b-cd7e297027aa

the microsoft help page for the sample can be found at:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165055(VS.80).aspx

and the sample itself is in the VS 2010 SDK SP1:
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=21835

there may be another way to do it with the new managed extensions, however, i did not locate samples for this for VS 2010.

Comment: also; it appears that with the VS SDK in 2010 you can create Item and Project templates, although i have not been able to successfully get the instance to show my customized template file

Comment: cool; thanks for updating the link Valamas! hope things work like you wanted. :)