# How do you change your app icon in visual studio 2013?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I'm new to visual studios and I just created this very short calculator and I want to put it on mediafire for people to download but I wanted to change the icon..

I've heard that you select your app in solution explorer and Project>Properties

But my properties menu seems different.

It saids calculator property pages.

It doesnt have the tabs like ~Publish~ or ~Applications~ where people said you change your icon.

My properties is like this:

Configuration: Active(Debug)

and some other stuff below it some complicated stuff(to me)

Why doesnt mine have what other people have? I just want to share my first ever app with a custom icon. Help please, will appreciate it.

Comment: You application would be an executable(.exe). right??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to change icons in Visual Studio 2012?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12087949/is-it-possible-to-change-icons-in-visual-studio-2012)

Comment: Not a duplicate of that question. that's about visual studio itself.

Answer (score 3):

Create a text file, rename it **res.rc**, edit it to contain the line:

```
201  ICON  "myicon.ico"
```

Add that file to your project. The file **myicon.ico** must exists.
*Note*: This is a bit hacky, the numerical vaulues should preferably be defined in a header.

Comment: The tools will be happier if you use res.rc, not res.rs.

Answer (score 2):

You might be confused because Visual Studio supports different languages, and its UI is not consistent across those languages. Since you tagged it C++, the "old" rules apply. An application icon is a so-called resource.

You have to provide an .ico file, and reference it in a .rc file. The resource compiler (RC) compiles it into a .res file, and the linker then adds it to the EXE.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, if you open the form in designer view, the properties window has an icon property that will allow you to browse for the icon of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, i spent two hours trying to change it without any success until i resized the icon, it should be 32x32 and another one for small icon -not sure if its necessary though- with 16x16.

visual studio creates two icons when create the project , one is called small.ico and one is name yourexe.ico, just replace those and make sure to have correct sizes.