# SSIS icons in Visual Studio 2013 lost color

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, ssis, business-intelligence

On installing Visual Studio 2013 and the required SSIS components, I found that all the icons for the SQL Server toolbox were showing up in Black and White.

I found the solution for VS 201**2** where I can bring some of the color back here:

[Is it possible to change icons in Visual Studio 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12087949/is-it-possible-to-change-icons-in-visual-studio-2012)

To do the same thing in 201**3**, I had to manually copy over files as is outlined here:

http://computerbeacon.net/blog/visualstudio2010iconsandt

However, my SSIS toolbox still is the ugly black and white, and I'd like to bring color back to it.  The only icons showing up with color are the third party components installed.

[image: A]

How do I bring color back to these icons?  Is there a *UI.DLL I can replace to get color back?

Answer (score 1):

I too am very dissatisfied with ssis toolbox icons and have been searching for a third party solution.  I did find this: http://computerbeacon.net/blog/visualstudio2010iconsandt  I have not yet tried it.  I'm still discussing this with my co-workers to see if we should fire up a virtual machine and test it out.

Comment: That solution only works on icons native to Visual Studio.  It does not affect the icons in the SSIS toolbox.  Please report back if your findings are different.