# Is it possible to change icons in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, user-interface, icons, visual-studio-2015

I've downloaded VS2015 CTP6 release.

Is there any way to replace VS2015 solution explorer's icons with VS2010 ones? :(

PS: yep, I hate new UI design ideology. My fav is Win7 Crystal style.=)

Solutions from here don't work

[Is it possible to change icons in Visual Studio 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12087949/is-it-possible-to-change-icons-in-visual-studio-2012)

http://computerbeacon.net/blog/visualstudio2010iconsandt

Comment: you can change the shortcut. Properties -> Change Icon

Comment: Aha, proof I'm not the only one!

Answer (score 5):

You can change the Shortcut icon: https://visualstudioextensions.vlasovstudio.com/2015/12/02/on-changing-visual-studio-2015-icon/

If you want to customize the icon in Solution Explorer, you need to write a VS Extension.